# Word file converter that removes compatibility mode

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, docx

I have a user who has a lot of files that need to be converted from .doc to docx. A fully batched process is not the right way to go but multiple files are needed. I think that a right-click in explorer would be good, and have got this working nicely but now need a converter that works!

I have tried the OFC.exe tool that is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericwhite/bulk-convert-doc-to-docx) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/32033/batch-convert-doc-to-docx-and-equivilent-for-other-office-formats). What is frustrating to me is that when i run the conversion, I find the doc is converted to docx, but it is still in compatibility mode.

I have also used the wordconv file converter as described at this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027102/why-does-wordconv-exe-randomly-return-14-when-called-from-a-net-windows-servic) but I cannot find any description of the command line.

I would like to use wordconv, because it doesn't need a ini file, it is already installed and made by MS so no issues with having to get new software purchased in the corporate environment. I don't really want to break out visual studio and get all COM'd up.

So: will wordconv work? do you have the command line? do i need another approach?